# Access serial console for a GCE VM that was recreated?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've had a few GKE nodes crash and be recreated with no details as to the cause. I don't know exactly where to go from here. I've logged in to the servers and checked the systemd(ugh) journal but it only contained the current boot (even with -b1); I suspect they recreated the boot disk from scratch for the replaced VM. I've looked at the serial console but it looks like it only goes back to the current boot.

All I really have from before the crash are IG, IGM, and GKE node pool Stackdriver logs that don't provide any information other than timestamps. I'd try to share them but it's literally nothing but timestamps, the principal, and the resources involved. My *wild hunch* is that some service used too much memory and forced some watchdog to OOM, but with no data I can't prove it.

Therefore:

I am looking for a way to view what was on the serial console immediately prior to the crash. I'm not sure this is available, which would be unfortunate as it's basically step one of professionalizing a datacenter. a) Does this exist? b) How to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the nodes in a GKE cluster are meant to be ephemeral, as yours got recreated, there is no way to see what happened in the serial console before the crash as those nodes no longer exist.
However you may take considerations for future events such as using the logging features and maybe send those to BigQuery with a [sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2). It's true that the internal information is way better than the one that is sent to Stackdriver Logging but if your nodes got recreated this normally means that failed in some health checks and they got auto repaired/recreated.

Edit:

Looking around I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#setting_project_and_instance_metadata) and indeed is possible, just add the following to your node pool metadata, keep in mind that you'll have to create a new one as the instance group metadata in the node pools is not editable:

Key: serial-port-logging-enable
Value: true

Comment: Yeah, I understand they're ephemeral. Do you know for sure if it's possible to route the serial console output to BigQuery? It'd need to log every line right up until the crash for it to be useful, meaning it'd need to monitor from the outside rather than from, say, fluentd.

Comment: Honestly I don't think that's possible/viable, sending all the information of the serial console means to send even the command outputs that are executed in the serial console, this is not exactly feasible or friendly, you'll get tons and tons of data which will be billed in BigQuery.
Instead I recommend you use your application logs and maybe send some internal error logs to SD, although keep in mind that at the end the objective is that you app can work with this kind of recreations.

Comment: Unfortunately the application logs nor any logs on the server itself are going to be useful as the VM is apparently crashing hard, before logs can be sent to SD. Typically, a datacenter will have serial consoles going to loggers that you can access independently of servers for just this reason.

Comment: You're right, this is possible, check the edit in the answer, if works for you, don't forget to accept it.